# Saving .dta: data frame with very long strings using R

Tags: r, stata, r-haven

I have a df with multiple variables, some are very long strings with up to 4500 characters. I would like to export this database as a `.dta` file.

I try to save it using haven's `write_dta()` function, but I get the following error message: `Error in write_dta_(data, normalizePath(path, mustWork = FALSE), version = stata_file_format(version),  : Writing failure: A provided string value was longer than the available storage size of the specified column.`

Here is an example of the issue:

```
library(haven)

longFun <- function(n) {
  do.call(paste0, replicate(5000, sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE), FALSE))
}

longString <- data.frame(VeryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryVeryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryverylongname = longFun(1), stringsAsFactors = F)
write_dta(longString,"tst.dta")
```

I am aware that `write_dta` has issues handling long strings (https://github.com/tidyverse/haven/issues/437) and that one possibility is to trim the strings ([Error in write_dta : A provided string value was longer than the available storage size of the specified column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61564935/error-in-write-dta-a-provided-string-value-was-longer-than-the-available-stora)). But it is essential for me to keep the full strings.

Is there any way to save variables with long strings as `.dta` files using R?

**Edit:**
I have tried the `readstata13::save.dta13` option suggested by @jay.sf but this has two issues: 1) Is not able to manage - i.e. it truncates - long variable names above 32-UTF characters, that `write_dta()` manages well. 2) It is significantly slower than `write_dta()`. Given that I have to save a very large dataset this is a relevant concern.

In sum is there any other approach that would allow me to

a) save as .dta a df with very long strings

b) retain original variable names (longer than 32-UTF characters)

c) do this in a relatively fast manner.

Answer (score 1):

Use `save.dta13` from the *readstata13* package.

*R:*

```
readstata13::save.dta13(longString, "tst.dta")
```

*Stata:*

```
. use "V:\tst.dta" 
. list

     +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | V1                                                                                                   |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | GZSPZGLLKOQHETKURLPKQDTZWTNHLDJDUSAFAXHFMPKUDIZURKIFLWQSXSFBLTPBGBLJKTDYJCHZOPZCFYKIMLGTQGDKRNBGUI.. |
     +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `save.dta13` does not work because the var names are too long. is there a way to either make `save.dta13` accept longer names or to use another package?

Comment: @Alex Please elaborate on _"does not work"_.

Comment: It produces the following error: `Varname to long. Resizing. Max size is 32.` It cuts my variable names after 32 characters.  I have edited the question so that the name reflects this length. The issue is that I have hundreds of variables with very long names, and I would like to keep them with their original name

Comment: @Alex **1.** That's no error, rather a message that they're getting cut, **2.** Your requirements don't seem to be possible according to [this Stata list entry](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1452366-number-of-characters-in-variable-names).

Comment: Dear @jay.sf thanks a lot for your replies. They are very useful and help me to get very close to what I would like to achieve. On point 1) you are right, is a warning rather than an error. Sorry for the imprecision. On point 2) this is no longer true. Indeed, recent stata versions manage long names. One the advantage of `haven` is precisely that it allows saving long names. Indeed, the following df `longString <- data.frame(VeryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryVeryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryverylongname = 1, stringsAsFactors = F)` can be saved using
`write_dta(longString,"tst.dta")`

Comment: @Alex I see, didn't know Stata upgraded long names. I'm not working with _haven_, though, because their `read_dta` throws tibbles. Regarding `save.dta13` and long names, I made very good experience with the _readstata13_ authors replying to user issues, I suggest to [open a ticket at their github](https://github.com/sjewo/readstata13/issues).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I will file the issue, but unfortunately I think the variable name problem relates to Stata13. Indeed they added the feature of having longer variable names from Stata14 onwards.

Comment: @Alex I believe the package name relates to the fact, that Stata file format changed significantly in v13, I know v14 and v15 features are also already implemented.

Comment: Excellent! thanks I have filed the issue!

Comment: @Alex Great, I would just mention that recent Stata versions manage long names, if they aren't aware of it yet.